# Regex for blockquotes to indent multiple paragraphs

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to intend multiple paragraph in `blockquote`, for example please see the image [image: multiple paragraph intended in blockquote]

The `RegEx` expression for this  which I am using:

```
 /^( *>[^\n]+(\n(?!def)[^\n]+)*\n*)+
```

By using this `RegEx` expression I am getting result like this:

[image]

The `RegEx` expression is from `marked.js` file. I have modified this expression to obtain the result but failed to obtain. I am not having good understanding of `RegEx`.

Comment: I think a [fiddle with what you have so far](http://jsfiddle.net) would help us help you.

Comment: Post an example of your multiple paragraphs and an example of how they should appear.